# Matherial path tree-output

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have column with matherial paths like

```
b
b1
b11  
c    
c1   
d    
e    
f    
g   
g1
```

How I can do desc output like this(tree-order desc output)?

```
g
g1
f
e
d
c
c1
b
b1
b11
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ascii function

```
create table t(col varchar(10));
insert into t
select 'b' union all
select 'b1' union all
select 'b11' union all
select 'c' union all
select 'c1' union all   
select 'd' union all    
select 'e' union all    
select 'f' union all    
select 'g' union all   
select 'g1';

select * from t 
order by 
ascii(col) desc, 
length(col) ;
```

Result is

```
col
g
g1
f
e
d
c
c1
b
b1
b11
```

SQLFiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaf954/4